# Windows License agreement (EULA) is always in English in OOBE even when language packs are installed

Tags: windows, system32

I am following the guide "how the oobexml works" from microsoft website to prepare an image for the PCs we are going to deliver to customers.

I am using windows 10 version 1809.

I added language packs for de-de and ja-jp. (I downloaded localized license files form the OEM partner site.)

Nevertheless, when going through OOBE after choosing German as the language, the Windows EULA is displayed in English.

My eulafilename in the %WINDIR%\System32\Oobe\Info\Oobe.xml is been ignored.

It is getting the EULA file from "C:\Windows\System32\de-de\Licenses\EntrepriseS"

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: You may try to run `%windir%\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe` twice, change the language and reboot each time.

Comment: Hi @harrymc thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it did not work.